# Write a list of values as separate columns to a CSV file using Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, csv

I am trying to write the elements of a list (each time I get from a for loop) as individual columns to a CSV file. But the elements are adding as an individual rows, but not columns.

I am new to python. What needs to be changed in my code? Please tell me

```
import csv
row=['ABC','XYZ','','','ABCD','']  #my list looks like this every time
with open('some.csv', 'w') as writeFile:
    writer = csv.writer(writeFile, delimiter=',', quotechar='"')
    for item in row:
        writer.writerow([item])
```

But I am getting the output as below:

```
ABC

XYZ

ABCD
```

My expected output is a below:

```
ABC XYZ    ABCD
```

Comment: use `writer.writerows[row]`

Comment: Still, its giving me the wrong output as below:

Comment: No need of `iteration` here. Use without `for`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are iterating over the list `row` and writing each element as a new row in your code when you do `writer.writerow([item])`.

Instead you want to write the entire row in one line using `writer.writerow`

```
import csv

row=['ABC','XYZ','','','ABCD','']  #my list looks like this every time

with open('some.csv', 'w') as writeFile:

    writer = csv.writer(writeFile, delimiter=',', quotechar='"')
    #Write the list in one row
    writer.writerow(row)
```

The file will look like

```
ABC,XYZ,,,ABCD,
```

Answer (score 1):

Actually you are writing in different rows, you don't need to do that. You can write your whole list as a single row. You need spaces so for that you can modify your list.

Comment: import csv

row=['ABC','XYZ','','','ABCD','']  #my list looks like this every time



with open('some.csv', 'w') as writeFile:
    writer = csv.writer(writeFile, delimiter=',', quotechar='"')
    writer.writerow(row)